# Call Azure graph REST API from javascript

Tags: azure

I want to create users in WAAD. For this i am using Azure Graph API. I want to consume this API from java script code.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly call any Azure **Management** REST API (this includes Azure AD) from a browser. That is because Azure **Management** APIs do not support CORS yet.

The only Azure APIs that do support CORS, thus are invokable from a Browser are Mobile Services REST API and Azure Storage Rest API Services.

Your only option is to proxy the management calls via server side code.